# Delphi Stack Info during Event Handling

Tags: delphi, events, stack, handler

When debugging events I would like to see the "complete" stack, specifically the actual event or method that triggered an event.

A simple example would be to drop a ComboBox on a form, and write an onChange event.  The onChange event will trigger when a user changes the comboBox (obviously), but it can also get triggered via other routines, eg, at startup, the formActivate will trigger it.

If I place a breakpoint in the OnChange event of the comboBox, I won't see the triggering stack.  Why is this, and how can I get this "other" stack info during debugging?

I know I can step through the event and it will eventually bring me back to the triggering code, this is not what I am looking for.

Thank you!

---

I thought I would post an image of how enabling dcu's worked.  Note that the FormCreate event actually appears in the stack now.

Here is an image of two different stack traces.  Breakpoint is exactly the same in both, note that after enabling debug dcu's in the second, I get stack information from my code (not just vcl/rtl).
[image]

Comment: Are you saying the debugger's **Call Stack** window is empty when your breakpoint is hit?

Comment: Thank you @David, this did work.  Could you make this an answer, and I will accept.

Comment: @Remy, no I do have a call stack in the debugger, it was just missing some items.

Comment: I am not following the downvote.  I think the question was pretty clear.  Was it too simplistic?  I don't think so... Here's a more complex example, when using a DBAware Component, eg, a DBComboBox the onChange event can be triggered in many different ways, eg, an onBeforePost, onFormActivate, on a dataset scroll, or by the user actually changing it.  These different execution paths were not in my call stack, at least not until I took David's advice.  My call stack was definitely missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are missing the RTL/VCL functions from the stack trace. To make them show up, enabled **Debug DCUs** in the project options.

Comment: Thank you @David.  It wasn't just RTL/VCL functions missing.  After enabling Debug DCU's, I saw my own code in the stack.  Specifically the FormCreate handler only appeared after enabling debug dcus.  I was surprised by this.  I will post an image of the two stack traces side by side to illustrate this.

Comment: see the original question for the resulting stack trace. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> After enabling Debug DCU's, I saw my own code in the stack.
>   Specifically the FormCreate handler only appeared after enabling debug
>   dcus. I was surprised by this.

See [this](http://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/stack_tracing.php):

**Stack frames for frame-based methods**

RTL and VCL units are compiled with "Stack Frames" option turned off. This means that any frame-based method will not be able to find short routines in RTL/VCL units.

However, this fact also have less obvious consequence. Consider this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStringList.Create;
end;
```

This code creates a simple memory leak by leaking instance of TStringList. A tracing tool will detect a leak and build call stack for it. Button1Click routine has stack frame due to "Stack Frames" option being enabled for your project. One may expect that frame-based tracing method will discover a call to Button1Click and add it to the call stack.

This is not so.

The stack frame for Button1Click allows method to identify **the caller** (in this case: TControl.Click). That's because stack frame does not contain information about routine *itself*. It contains information about *the caller*: **return address**. Return address for Button1Click routine will point to TControl.Click.

But what about Button1Click? Since TStringList is a class from RTL - it's compiled without "Stack Frames" option. Thus, constructor does not have stack frame (because it's very simple code and do not require stack frame). Therefore, it's not possible for frame-based tracing method to identify Button1Click routine.

Comment: thank you for this.  So I guess the suggestion is that by enabling debug dcu's, the function call was no longer "Simple" (according to the link), and therefore a stackframe was created?  Sorry if I am misunderstanding.  I am just trying to understand the link between enabling debug dcu's and stack frame creation.

Comment: Debug version of code may be created with "Stack Frames" option on, or with "Optimization" option off, or both. Any way will lead to generation of frames. Source code itself is not changed.

Comment: See provided link for more detailed explanation.